# Haskell while loop where recursion simply won't do?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, monads

I am somewhat of a beginner to Haskell and declarative languages in general, but as a thought experiment, I decided that an interesting coding exercise would be to implement something like the [Hashcash algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash).  If you aren't familiar with it, basically it is the grandfather of the Bitcoin Proof of Work scheme.  It specifies the creation of an email header that when hashed into a SHA-1 digest, should have the first `n` bits as zero where `n` is the difficulty of the Proof of Work.  This is designed to be trivial to validate for the recipient while a modest expense of CPU cycles for senders with the intent of discouraging mass spamming operations.  This was an interesting exercise to me because it allowed me to learn how to work with ByteStrings and bits in Haskell, while trying to tackle a very specific but potentially massive imperative series of steps in a functional and declarative way.  Essentially the sender must increment a counter and rebuild the potential header, test it, and if that particular test is valid then we have a valid header.  It is designed to be exponentially harder as the difficulty increases.

My problem at this point is that difficulty of 1 and 2 bits as zero seems to work fine, but once I get to 3 or more difficulty I appear to be caught in an endless loop until the stack blows up.  Rather than use a while loop, I attempted to do this in a recursive way, so I specified the strictness of counter such prior thunks must be computed before moving to the next step, and I no longer receive an overflow, but I still appear to be caught in an endless loop (or perhaps the performance is so bad that I never get to the end?)

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module HashCash where

import Data.Int
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.Char
import Data.Function
import System.Random
import Data.Bits
import Data.Either
import Data.Binary.Strict.Get
import System.IO as SIO
import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BU
import Data.ByteString.Base64 as B64
import Data.ByteString.Conversion as BCON
import Data.ByteArray as BA
import Crypto.Random
import Crypto.Hash


startingCounter :: Int32
startingCounter = 1
difficulty :: Int
difficulty = 4
template = "X-Hashcash: 1:{:{:{::{:{"
dateTemplate = "YYMMDDhhmmss"
address = "a@a"

-- example date because I dont want to mess with date formatting just now
exampleDate = "150320112233"

convertToString :: ByteString -> String
convertToString b = BU.toString b

convertFromString :: String -> ByteString
convertFromString s = BU.fromString s

convertIntToString :: Int -> String
convertIntToString a = convertToString . BCON.toByteString' $ a

encodeInt32 :: Int32 -> ByteString
encodeInt32 a = B64.encode . BCON.toByteString' $ a

mahDecoder :: Get Word32
mahDecoder = do
  first32Bits <- getWord32be
  return first32Bits

firstBitsZero :: (Bits a) => a -> Int -> Bool
firstBitsZero val num = Data.List.foldl' (\acc x -> (testBit val x) && acc) True [1..num]

formatTemplate :: String -> [String] -> String
formatTemplate base [] = base
formatTemplate base (x:xs) = 
   let splix = (Data.List.Split.splitOn "{" base) :: [String]
       splixHead = Data.List.head splix ++ x
       splixTail = Data.List.tail splix
       concatSplitTail = Data.List.init $ Data.List.concatMap (++ "{") splixTail
   in formatTemplate (splixHead ++ concatSplitTail) xs

get16RandomBytes :: (DRG g) => g -> IO (ByteString, g)
get16RandomBytes gen = do
  let a = randomBytesGenerate 16 gen
  return $ a

getBaseString :: ByteString -> Int32 -> String
getBaseString bs counter = 
  let encodedVal = B64.encode bs
      encodedCounter = encodeInt32 counter
      baseParams = [(convertIntToString difficulty), exampleDate, address, (convertToString encodedVal), (convertToString encodedCounter)]
  in formatTemplate template baseParams

hashSHA1Encoded :: ByteString -> ByteString
hashSHA1Encoded bs =
  let hashDigest = hash bs :: Digest SHA1
      byteString = B.pack . BA.unpack $ hashDigest
  in B64.encode byteString

-- Pass a counter and if the first 20 bits are zero then return the same counter value else increment it
-- signifying it is time to test the next number (NOTE: recursive style, may overflow stack)
testCounter :: ByteString -> Int32 -> Int32
testCounter rb !counter = 
  let baseString = getBaseString rb counter
      hashedString = hashSHA1Encoded $ convertFromString baseString
      !eitherFirst32 = runGet mahDecoder hashedString
      incCounter = counter + 1
  in case eitherFirst32 of
    (Left first32, _) -> testCounter rb incCounter
    (Right first32, _) -> if (firstBitsZero first32 difficulty)
                           then counter
                           else testCounter rb incCounter

generateHeader :: IO String
generateHeader = do
  g <- getSystemDRG
  (ran, _) <- get16RandomBytes g
  let counter = testCounter ran startingCounter
  return $ getBaseString ran counter

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  header <- generateHeader
  SIO.putStrLn header
  return ()
```

So clearly this doesn't work and I am not terribly sure why just yet, but I was trying to think about better ways I can solve this.  Is it possible for instance to create a `sequence` of monadic actions for `testCounter` then possibly do a `takeWhile` on the condition of each action result to see if I need to take anymore?

If not, then does Proof of Work algorithms fall into that class of applications that just don't make sense for declarative functional programming?

Comment: Close voter, care to elaborate why you think that I did not elaborate my problem clearly?

Comment: 1. This example is very far from minimal. 2. `testCounter` explodes the stack because it is not tail recursive (no amount of strictness annotations will help you here, and the one on `!eitherFirst32` does nothing - you pattern match on `eitherFirst32` immediately after the let binding, so it will be evaluated to WHNF anyways.) I have no idea what it actually does, so I couldn't tell you how to make it tail recursive. 3. All these conversions and encoding/decoding will almost certainly kill performance.. e.g. `firstBitsZero` is very inefficient - `num` comparisons to zero instead of one!

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for the information, can you elaborate what you mean by `num comparisons to zero instead of one`?  I have to test the first `num` bits, can this be done in less than `num` number of operations (perhaps binary OR on num bits against mask) == 0?)

Comment: @user2407038 The constant encoding and hashing after each increment of the counter is required by the algorithm.  It is supposed to perform badly.  It is a Proof of Work algorithm, that's kinda the point!  It is not supposed to blow the stack however and I imagine it is supposed to run at LEAST as fast as the Java implementation I whipped up.

Comment: Nice task. It's hard to see what's going wrong, though. Can you try to test your functions and see if you can reduce the issue to some part? BTW `formatTemplate` looks suspicious, the first argument could explode exponentially fast.

Comment: `firstBitsZero` could be a `foldr`: `foldl'` always scans all the list so there's no early exit (short-circuit) when a bit is found to be wrong. Minor: why `get16RandomBytes` in the IO monad? Suggestion: you can use `Debug.Trace.trace` to do some printf-like debugging. E.g. when some key function is called you could try to trace its arguments so they get printed.

Comment: @chi Good suggestion on foldr! I just want 16 random bytes for the random part of the Hashcash header. That can be precomputed and in fact when I run this in ghci it shows the complete string of the header minus the counter part on the sys out. It is stuck incrementing through possible numbers thst satisfy where the first 4 bits are zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the efficiency of your code.  You really are entering an infinite loop because you have two bugs:

1. `firstBitsZero` is checking for "one" bits, not "zero" bits.
2. You are applying `firstBitsZero` to the Base64 encoded version of the hash, instead of the actual bits of the hash.

It's no surprise that you're having trouble generating hashes whose Base64 (i.e., ASCII!) representation "starts with" (but see below) more than a small number of one bits and/or zero bits.

If you fix these two problems, you'll find that your program, when compiled with `-O2` optimizations on, generates a HashCash for 20 bits in under a minute.  Still too slow, but obviously much improved.

You still have a number of bugs that make your program incompatible with an actual hashcash:

```
SPOILERS



SPOILERS



SPOILERS
```

- You are checking if the *least* significant bits of the first 32 bit word are zero, instead of the most significant bits (and you are assuming the bit index for `testBit` starts with 1, but it actually starts with zero).
- You are hashing the entire header including the `X-HashCash:` prefix, which isn't part of the string that should be hashed.

After fixing these, it looks like your program works fine.  For example, here's a hashcash generated by your program at difficulty 20, which we can verify starts with 20 zero bits using your `mahDecoder`.

```
> runGet mahDecoder (hashSHA1 "1:20:150320112233:a@a::2go+qPr1OxIigymGiuEDxw==:NTE3MDM0")
(Right 753,"[\191\GS\237iw\NAKIp\193\140)BZI_")
>
```

Again, note that the string to check excludes the `X-HashCash` header.

Nice choice of project, by the way.

Comment: Awesome!  I can't believe I missed those two bugs.  Seems obvious now.  Also I wasn't aware that that the header prefix isn't included.  Will definitely fix that. I will also make the foldr performance improvement in firstBitsZero that another user suggests.  And thank you for wrapping your code in a spoiler tag.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Any thoughts on possibly using a takeWhile against [1..] for testing an incremented counter here?  I am wondering if this is safer or more efficient than using recursion.

Comment: I tried the takeWhile approach as opposed to recursion and it worked fantastic after fixing the bugs and fixed the firstBitsZero function.  I see what you mean about the performance though.  To be fair though this appears to run slightly faster than my Java implementation after doing the -02 optimization flag.  Will probably look into how I can improve the performance of this.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @maple_shaft Note that [`takeWhile` uses recursion internally](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#takeWhile). All forms of looping in Haskell ultimately involve recursion.